# WP8.1 RT - Changing pixel color

Tags: c#, colors, windows-phone-8.1, runtime, pixel

I've been working on some Windows Phone 8.1 RT app's lately which require quite alot of icons. For iOS and Android we can use White on Black icons and turn them into the right color(s) through code. But for WP8.1 it seems quite impossible to run it fast.

```
class ColoredImage
{
    public static WriteableBitmap GetColoredImage(WriteableBitmap bitmap,  Color color)
    {
        var result = bitmap;

        for (int i = 0; i < (result.PixelWidth); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0;  j < result.PixelHeight; j++)
            {
                if (result.GetPixel(i, j) == Colors.Black)
                {
                    result.SetPixel(i, j, Colors.Transparent);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.SetPixel(i, j, color);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I got this class changing the colors of a WriteableBitmap but it takes about 15 seconds to change the colors of a 62x62 image. Is there anything I am doing wrong, and on what can I improve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your algo of reading an image finding pixel and changing their colors is a time consuming process. You have got two ways in which you can do it at a faster pace
1) Using `Segoe MDL2 Assets` You can use these pre installed font family which contains most of the basic images. Benefit is since these are vector images changing foreground would change the color instantly. Search for CharacterMap and then this font in your system and you will find all available fonts
2) If you are not able to find your particular image in charmap then you will have to create path images using blend which is similar to converting images to vector and then you can easily change color.